# Do undefined expressions have values that can be compared?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So a question from a math quiz has continued to baffle me, I'm gonna cut to the chase so this is the math problem:

Find the value of $x$ given:

$$\frac{x+5}{x^2+x} = \frac{1}{x+1}$$

basically if tried to solved, both fractions end up as undefined, but the teacher said since they're both undefined they're both equal. Need help.

Comment: Assume $x\neq 0$ and that $x\neq -1$, else you have undefined expressions.  Multiply both sides by $x(x+1)$.  This leaves us with $x+5 = x$ and that $5=0$.  Since this is never true, we get that there are no values of $x$ satisfying the equation where the values are defined.  If your teacher decides they want to allow for $x=-1$ to mean that the LHS and RHS are "both undefined" and thus "equal" or to mean that both LHS and RHS are "both infinity" and thus "equal" is up to how you define things... but I would advocate for saying that even $x=-1$ should not be considered a solution here.

Comment: Answer depends on exact problem set-up. We can consider set-up where every expression of kind $a/b$, where $a>0$ and $b=0$ has the same value, however this set-up is not default, so it must be said explicitly.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I wasn't aware of expressions with a denominator as zero has the same value in some math set-ups as mentioned in your comment. Can you provide an example where it's the case? Thanks for answering the question btw.